# Storage demand and best options

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am an IT admin and am having problems with increasing storage demands from my users. They constantly email big file attachments and I have to keep purchasing more storage space. In order to fix that problem I limit my employee profile size and sometimes I have to cut the storage which makes everyone unhappy. Any suggestions for minimizing user’s storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've tagged this with SharePoint, I am assuming you have a SharePoint farm setup. If so, I think you need to get your users to send links instead of documents and to keep files in SharePoint. It's a hard but not impossible transition to make. If you want to be really hardcore about it, do not let users attach documents on internal emails period. Everything should be put into SharePoint and linked to. I would not use OneDrive for Business though. The problem I've seen is that people just use it like a shared drive and it ends up as unorganized and space taking as email was. You need to really use SharePoint where documents live in centralized workspaces instead of personal libraries.

http://info.easydynamics.com/blog/minimize-storage-consumption-with-sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

Scalability and increased storage requirements is very common. MS has recently announced OneDrive for Business will have unlimited storage for its users. Sounds like you already have a subscription to this so your users would qualify

http://blogs.office.com/2014/10/27/onedrive-now-unlimited-storage-office-365-subscribers/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn232145(v=office.15).aspx